# wp_list_pages Removing the Title

Tags: php, wordpress

Good morning,

I am using this snippet of code to pull up a sub nav in my side menu that only shows the children of the current page. But the code is automatically generating a title to the subnav called "Pages"

How do I remove this title?

```
<?php
    wp_list_pages( array('child_of' => $post->ID,'depth' => 1,));
?>
```

http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/landfordstone-wordpress/?page_id=752

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer myself with this edit of the code above.

```
<?php
    wp_list_pages( array(
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'depth' => 1,
        'title_li' => ''
));
?>
```